# Make UINavigationBar translucent

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am making with a slideshow in it. I want the navigation bar to look the same as in the photo app. How do I get this transparency?

I have tried:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor clearColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);

}   

UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
background.frame = self.navigationController.toolbar.bounds;
background.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
BOOL isIOS5 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 5;
self.navigationController.toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.toolbar insertSubview:background atIndex: (isIOS5 ? 1 : 0)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `translucent` property of `UINavigationBar`. Try:

```
[[self.navigationController navigationBar] setTranslucent:YES];
```